# ¿Que tipo de formato usa wordpress para guardar un array en la base de datos?

Tags: base-de-datos, wordpress, woocommerce

[image: Tabla de bd de Wordpres]

Buenas quisiera realizar mis propios insert a la bd de woordpres, pero quisiera saber que tipo de formato es ese en el que guarda información woodpress

```
a:8:{
s:12:"price_is_per";i:1;
s:17:"price_time_option";s:4:"days";
s:10:"max_length";i:0;
s:9:"trial_per";s:0:"";
s:17:"trial_time_option";s:0:"";
s:21:"next_payment_due_date";i:1679070778;
s:11:"order_total";d:300;s:4:"sync";b:0;
}
```

Comment: La respuesta de @CristianZúñiga es correcto, sin embargo no recomiendo hacer insert personalizados, wordpress ya permite guardar información en sus tablas con funciones como update_post_meta(), update_user_meta() y update_option(), revisa esas opciones antes de hacer querys personalizados.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress usa el formato serialize para guardar arrays y objetos en la base de datos. El ejemplo que muestras es un array serializado:

Una a: para indicar que es un array, el número de elementos del array (8), llave del primer elemento (s:12:"price_is_per";), valor del primer elemento (i:1;) y así sucesivamente por cada elemento.

[Pregunta similar en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67124730/how-to-work-with-serialize-array-database-wordpress-to-make-crud-operation) -
[Fuente](https://wpengine.com/support/wordpress-serialized-data/)